# InstallShield 2009: Remove a dll (being used by explorer.exe for context menu) during uninstall without any warning message

Tags: dll, contextmenu, uninstallation, installshield-2009

**Install Shield Premier 2009: Basic MSI Project**
I have a dll that is supposed to be removed during uninstall.

But this **dll** is being **used by explorer.exe**, it is used for generating windows explorer context menus with their icons(same as the menu items, icons we see when we right click on any file/folder and see the **WinRAR items, icons**).

**Manually**, I have to **unregister the dll** and **close explorer.exe** from task manager and again run explorer.exe. Then I can delete the dll.

So from Install Shield how to delete this dll without any problem(as we see while uninstalling WinRAR or other software there is no problem no message boxes shown and the related context menu icons also removed).